# How to combine a regex selector with :after?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I currently have a few `<a>` tags, and I want to append an icon to a few of them. I want to exclude all the tags which have an `<img>` child.

I can select all the right  tags using the following selector:

```
a[href^='google'] > :not(img) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I combine it with the ::after pseudo selector, I do not get anything:

```
a[href^='google'] > :not(img)::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with a playground

```css
a[href^='google']> :not(img) {
  background: yellow;
}

a[href^='google']> :not(img)::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/google-submit-url-1516800645.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="google.com">
  <p> There should be an orange square after this link while the link with the image should have no orange square </p>
</a>
```

How can I select all the pseudo afters for the children that match the given regex?

NOTE: This is not asking to select the parent of a child, but to select the children of a parent.

Comment: no space --> `not(img):after` and there is no such selector actually (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/8620333)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I am not trying to select the parent, I am trying to select the pseudo elements of the children of a tag

Comment: is this what you want; https://jsfiddle.net/hfc61L09/ ? if so, I will edit the duplicate

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cq531rb8/ I think you're missing a `display: block;` in your `::after` pseudo element